# Open menu when hover on icon menu JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have been searching for a solution but I can't find any that fits to what I woluld like to get. I have an icon and want the dropdown menu opened when HOVER in sreen size larger than *980px*, and then when CLICK in screen size smaller than  980px.

This is the code.

```js
/*Hide menu by default*/
$("#menu").hide();

/*When menu button is clicked, toggle the menu*/
$("#menu-btn").click(function() {
  $("#menu").slideToggle();
});


$("#menuser").hide();

/*When menu button is clicked, toggle the menu*/
$("#ser_btn").click(function() {
  $("#menuser").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Hamburger menu toggle button-->
<div id="menu-btn">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/icon.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;"></a>
</div>

<!--Menu-->
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>INICIO</li>
    <li>LA BELLE</li>
    <li id="ser_btn">SERVICIOS
      <ul id="menuser">
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>NOTICIAS</li>
    <li>CONTACTO</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  // check the event to listen to
  var evt = $(window).width() > 980 ? // if the window width is greater than 980
    "mouseenter mouseleave" :         // then lesten for mouseenter and mousleave
    "click";                          // otherwise a click event

  // hide it by default
  $("#menu").hide();

  // on the event evt toggle the menu
  $("#menu-btn").on(evt, function() {
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
  });
  
  // hide it by default
  $("#menuser").hide();

  // on the event evt toggle the menu
  $("#ser_btn").on(evt, function() {
    $("#menuser").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Hamburger menu toggle button-->
<div id="menu-btn">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/icon.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;"></a>
</div>

<!--Menu-->
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>INICIO</li>
    <li>LA BELLE</li>
    <li id="ser_btn">SERVICIOS
      <ul id="menuser">
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
        <li>PELUQUERIA</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>NOTICIAS</li>
    <li>CONTACTO</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this using CSS in most cases:

```
<div id="menu-btn">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/icon.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;"></a>
</div>

<!--Menu-->
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>INICIO</li>
    <li>CONTACTO</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<style>
  nav#menu { display: none }
  #menu-btn:hover + nav#menu, nav#menu:hover { display:block }
</style>
```

Or more often I would nest the `nav` inside the `button`

```
<div id="menu-btn">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/icon.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;"></a>
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>INICIO</li>
      <li>CONTACTO</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<style>
  #menu-btn nav { display: none }
  #menu-btn:hover nav, #menu-btn nav:hover { display:block }
</style>
```